# Angularjs, the controller can't read from the factory?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a services.js file where I placed my facotry:

```
.factory('dataShare',function($rootScope){

 var service = {};
  service.data = false;
  service.sendData = function(data){
      this.data = data;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');

  };
  service.getData = function(){
    return this.data;
      console.log('this.data')
  };
  return service;

})
```

And my controllers, in the controller.js file look like this:

```
 .controller('recommendedJobsCtrl', function($q,$scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate,$window,$http,dataShare) {

$scope.text='hey';
 $scope.post=function(){
dataShare.sendData($scope.text);
 console.log('here')
  }   

})
.controller('jobPostCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,dataShare) {
  $scope.text = '';
 $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
var text =  dataShare.getData();    
$scope.text = text;
console.log(text)
       });
})
```

When I did console.log, i realized that the service.getData isn't wokring, i.e the receiving controller (jobPostCtrl) isn't getting anything. 
How can i fix this?

Comment: You put `console.log()` after a return statement, it will never be run.

Comment: `return this.data;` shouldn't this be `return service.data;`?

Comment: here `sendData` is a part of `service = {}` object. try `dataShare.service .sendData`

Comment: @developer033 thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Adrian they didn't make a difference :/

Comment: @varit05 no difference

Comment: can you please provide plunker for this?

Comment: @varit05 https://plnkr.co/edit/X8E677WwKTKWHtNmzXGD

Comment: something wrong with the plunker

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

            sampleApp.factory('dataShare',function($rootScope){
                var service = {};
                service.data = false;
                service.sendData = function(data){
                    this.data = data;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
                };
                service.getData = function(){
                    return this.data;
                    console.log('this.data')
                };
                return service;
            });

            sampleApp.controller('recommendedJobsCtrl', function($q,$scope,$window,$http,dataShare) {
                $scope.text='hello world!';
                $scope.post=function(){
                    dataShare.sendData($scope.text);
                    console.log('sent: ' + $scope.text);
                }   
            });

            sampleApp.controller('jobPostCtrl', function($scope,dataShare) {
                $scope.text = '';
                $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
                    var text =  dataShare.getData();
                    $scope.text = text;
                    console.log('received: ' + $scope.text);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="sampleApp">
        <div ng-controller="recommendedJobsCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="text" />
            <button ng-click="post()">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="jobPostCtrl">
            <p>{{text}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the issue remains, the data isn;t being sent because console.log('recieved' + $scope.text); isnt showing up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use
$rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared',this.data);

and  $scope.$on('data_shared',function(event,data){

$scope.$scope.text=data;

});

Comment: I thought I included the services script in the index and in my JobPost job i did combine it as follows:  <div ng-controller="jobPostCtrl">. Is there something I am missing ?